# Add attributes (Brands) in Product using woocommerce API

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Hello I want to upload to the product - attribute Brands with the help of API

[{"id":0,"name":"brands","position":1,"visible":true,"variation":true,"options":["Toshiba"]}]

It incorrectly is placed out in products. Because of this, it does not appear in the filters.

The photo shows how

What am I doing wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgi5v.png)

Answer (score 0):

do It like this:

```
[
    {
        "id":0,
        "name": "Brands",
        "position": 0,
        "visible": true,
        "variation": true,
        "options":["Toshiba"]
    }
]
```

Capitalised `name`, `Brands`.

the `position` is `0` as counting starts from 0.

and the `id` is maybe varied. To get the id for the `Brands` attribute goto: `Products` > `Attributes` then click `Edit` under `Brands`. Then, on the address bar of your browser, you will see something like this:

`https://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product&page=product_attributes&edit=3`

the number after `edit=` at the end is the `id` for `Brands`. In my case, it is `3`.

I hope that solves the problem.